# Android Studio Online Radio app(java) from API

Tags: java, android

I have to do a project for univeristy in android studio a radio online who take elements from API(java language). For first i've done the adapterview(with a list) and take elements from api, My question is how can i implement media player in my code to play the stream from api(i have the code for media  player but works only for one link and i dont know how to implement to this project.
I have put my code there:https://textuploader.com/tsu8j
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfwph.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see `onPlayClick` which is called on the play button, right now I always change the URL to the radio station which is clicked on just to show you how can you change the URL for media to be played in mediaplayer.
YOu can yourself think of logic to show the `pause' button and updating them according to the song is played.

Right now this snippet is to show you how you can changes the ongoing radio to different when you clicked upon that.

`getAdapterPosition()`: I am taking leverage of this to know which row's `Play` button is clicked so that accordingly I can switch to that radio station.

**mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()**: so that I don't block the main thread.

**setOnPreparedListener** because we want to `start` our mediaPlayer when it is done prepared and as we have done it asynchronously we have to listen for the callback to know when to start our media player.

**setOnErrorListener** to know if there is some error while playing some media, this was helpful as in your case out of 10 stations only 5 or 6 are working and others are throwing error and this callback actually helped me to know why exactly media was not played.

**stopPlaying** There is `mediaPlayer.stop();` and `mediaPlayer.reset();` this are to make sure that before new media data is set using **mediaPlayer.setDataSource** already playing media is stopped and the data is reset.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

// creating a variable for array list and context.
private ArrayList<RadioStation> radioStationArrayList;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
// creating a constructor for our variables.
public Adapter(ArrayList<RadioStation> radioStationArrayList, Context context) {
    this.radioStationArrayList = radioStationArrayList;
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // below line is to inflate our layout.
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.course_rv_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // setting data to our views of recycler view.
    RadioStation modal = radioStationArrayList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(modal.getName());
    Picasso.get().load(modal.getFavicon()).into(holder.favicon);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    // returning the size of array list.
    return radioStationArrayList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // creating variables for our views.
    private TextView name;
    private ImageView favicon;
    private Button play;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idName);
        favicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImg);
        play = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(view -> onPlayClick());
    }

    public void onPlayClick() {
        stopPlaying();
        startPlaying();
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioStationArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl_resolved());
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                Log.v("DINKAR", "Started");
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener((mp, what, extra) -> {
                Log.e("DINKAR", "Error");
                return false;
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DINKAR", "failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }
}

}
```

**Note:** many of the radio stations are having issues MediaPlayer were not able to play those.

I used https://textuploader.com/tsu8j to get your adapter class code and using your screenshot of the app created layout XML file on my own so that I can run the app to test it out before giving you any snippet

[image]

Comment: can you send to me the entire project if you already make it working please? because i still have issues when i click on play. Can you send to me the entire project if you make it working please, on wetransfer,my email:antal_bogdan_catalin@yahoo.com

Comment: I pushed it in GitHub you can try that from there.
https://github.com/dk19121991/RadioSample
Do let me know if you have any further question or any queries

Comment: still gettings error with your code "E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)"

Comment: Yes this is for the radiostation which are not working

Comment: Try manele fm, digi fm and few more working one,

Comment: Working one : Radio Manele FM , Deep House Radio , Digi FM , Pro FM and Dance FM, everything else is not working radio station there might be something wrong with those stations.
also please take the latest pull from github

Comment: you da best,thanks alot!!

Comment: no issues, glad I could be of any help.

Comment: you know others players to use to play all the fm posts?or how can i play all the posts and the code if you have,the api is:https://de1.api.radio-browser.info/json/stations/search?limit=10&countrycode=RO&hidebroken=true&order=clickcount&reverse=true

Comment: I think you can create another question for the issues with those radio endpoints, because those need completely different aspect, as the scope for this question was to know how can we change the radio station using mediaplayer.
I can try to take a jibe on that one then.

Comment: sure no issues at all, you too have a nice day, will take a look into your new question regarding those stations not working with Mediaplayer

Comment: If you are still there, one more question. When i click on play i want the text to chage to "pause" and when i click on pause to go back to "play" but to stop not to start again,how can i do that?

Comment: as I said this not the perfect code and was the bare minimum to get you started to change the different radio station and then you have to write the logic for updating text and all, try to write the logic by your self and if you stuck into something you are always welcome to create a new question on StackOverflow so anyone in the community can help you.

Comment: can you please upvote the answer as you liked the solution and it also fixed your problem, upvote do help in motivation to continue the contribution to help others.